# MongoClientURI connection string throwing error "com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream"

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

```
public void MongoDBClient(String user, String pwd, String dbName, String collectionName) {
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://" + user + ":" + pwd + "@cluster0.mff6p.mongodb.net/"
            + dbName + "?retryWrites=true&w=majority&connectTimeoutMS=30000&socketTimeoutMS=30000");

    try (MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri)) {
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
        Document query = new Document("_id", new ObjectId("5f05e46281048f54ac98c455"));
        Document result = collection.find(query).iterator().next();
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("Test3: " + result.getString("Cluster"));
    }
}
```

Getting exception in the above code -

```
    INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-01.mff6p.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:580)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:445)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:299)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Can anyone help me, i think there is an issue with the connection string url, MongoClientURI...

Comment: This indicates that the peer closed the connection early. Check the server logs.

Comment: Test the mongo shell with that connection string, and use the  `--verbose` option, that should give you a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that your connection was terminated by the mongo server. It could have multiple reasons and best way to debug is to look at the server logs.

Usually the following is the issue:

From documentation:

> For long running applications, it is often prudent to enable
> "keepAlive" with a number of milliseconds. Without it, after some
> period of time you may start to see "connection closed" errors for
> what seems like no reason.

Try to enable to `keepAlive` property.

```
server: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 100,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; 

const dburl = "mongodb+srv://" + user + ":" + pwd + "@cluster0.mff6p.mongodb.net/"
        + dbName + "?retryWrites=true&w=majority&connectTimeoutMS=30000&socketTimeoutMS=30000";

MongoClient.connect(dburl,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true},(err,client) => {

                  if(err){
                      console.log("Error",err);
                   }
                  else{
                      console.log("Connected");
                  }  
});
```